# Type Error for Instance method defined on Mongoose Schema

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am getting a TypeError on calling one of the instance methods defined in the models from the controllers.

**Controller:**

This is my code in Controller:

```js
var Area = require('../../models/area');

Area.findOne({_id: 'Test'}).then((a) => {
    a.getChildren().then((area) => {console.log(area)})
})
```

and it returns this error:

> ```
> TypeError: a.getChildren is not a function
> ```

**Models:**

This is my code in Models:

```js
areaSchema.method({
  getChildren: function() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      this.model('Area').find({path: {$regex: '/' + this.path + '/'}}).exec.then((areas) => {
        return resolve(areas)
      }).catch((error) => reject(error))
    })
  }
})

    module.exports = Area;
```

**Node console:**

I also tried in node console as well:

```js
var Area = require('./models/area')
var a = new Area({name: 'test', type: 'test'})
a.getChildren().then((area) => {console.log(area)})
```

and it also returns the same error:

> ```
> TypeError: a.getChildren is not a function
> ```

Comment: `areaSchema.methods.getChildren = function () {` - You don't name an anonymous function assignment, which is why the `=` sign is there.

Comment: It was in the documentation tho. http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/methods-statics.html. 
Even removing the name doesn't help.

Comment: You do realize you are pointing at 2.7 release documentation when the current release is 5.1.2. Old and lots of mistakes. Look at the new documentation http://mongoosejs.com/. Also that's a "static model method" and not an "instance method", which is what you are doing here.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, have changed my code according to 
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_Schema-method
Still getting the same error though.

Comment: you didn't export `areaSchema` in model file